# How do I revert D8 behavior back to what it was in Android Studio 3.1.x?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-d8

**This is really a question for the Android (Studio) developer support team at Google.** Please let me know if there is a better channel for this.

### Background

I noticed an increasing number of libart.so crashes being reported in Google Play Console for my app. The same crashes don't show up in Crashlytics, I can't reproduce them myself, and they only seem to impact a few dozen users. I am not including any details of these crashes because I don't think it is relevant to my question, but I am open to be convinced otherwise.

I found a small number of reports about similar issues, for example [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/86a2ou/play_store_crash_report_with_libartso/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9d07b8/hopefully_it_is_not_fully_inappropriate_have/). These gave me the impression that the root cause may be the Android build system and in particular the D8 compiler.

I think these crashes started to happen after I released a new version of my app built with Android Studio 3.2.1. Previously, I was using the latest 3.1.x Android Studio build, which was already using D8 by default (right?), so turning D8 completely off seems a bit heavy handed. And this brings us to my...

### Question

How do I revert D8 behavior back to what it was in the latest Android Studio 3.1.x build while using Android Studio 3.2.1?

Bonus question: The first bullet point under "Behavior changes" of the [Android gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for version 3.2.0 is "Desugaring with D8 is now enabled by default." Does this desugaring do anything if I am not using Java8 features but I am using Kotlin?